# Can I get the pelts that were on the back of my horse back when I die?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I had a few pelts, including a legendary bear pelt on the back of my horse. On the way back to the camp I was ambushed by some bandits, and unfortunately they did manage to defeat me.

I'm not sure yet how exactly the death mechanics work in this game, but I respawned with some money lost. But also all my pelts were gone from my horse. I noticed at that point that my last manual save game was quite a bit ago, so I wasn't willing to reload to fix this.

Is this an intended part of the penalty for dying? Or is there a way to get those pelts back that I had stored on my hose?

Answer (score 1):

> **What Are Legendary Animals And Their Benefits**
>   These animals are unique animals of a specific species and when killed they drop legendary pelts, these pelts are highly valuable and can be used to craft trappers and special clothing items.
>   If you somehow lose the legendary pelt it will be transported to the Trapper so you will never miss this reward once you get it.
>   Furthermore collecting these animals also completes one of your requirement towards the Compendium.

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUx9w.png)

Yo you can get the legendary back

Comment: I have moved your screenshot into text, could you provide a link to the actual site where you took the screenshot from?

Comment: I have found what I believe is the source to that screenshot. https://prodigygamers.com/2018/10/25/red-dead-redemption-2-location-of-all-legendary-animals/

Answer (score 0):

Non-legendary pelts that are on your horse when you die will simply disappear (presumed stolen).

I have now learnt through bitter experience that if you've spent ages finding a three-star animal and managed to kill it cleanly enough to get a "perfect" pelt, the only logical next course of action is to gallop at full pace to camp or the nearest trapper and don't stop for any man/woman/beast along the way.

Make sure that you prioritise appropriate perfect pelts to Pearson if you want all of the satchel upgrades.